# Not able to run sample heathkit project FitStoreandRetrieveHealthKitData on iPhone

Tags: ios8, xcode6, healthkit

I have downloaded sample Health-kit app (**FitStoreandRetrieveHealthKitData**)from apple developer site. Trying to run it on my iPhone with **Xcode** 6 beta.
But failed to run app on device and getting error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCalories
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/95F193C0-52CE-47E0-92C4-0BF436AEB3AE/Fit.app/Fit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/HealthKit.framework/HealthKit
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/95F193C0-52CE-47E0-92C4-0BF436AEB3AE/Fit.app/Fit
```

Can any one has solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCalories was renamed to HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed.  Make sure you're building the project with the version of the iOS 8 SDK that corresponds to the version of iOS 8 you have installed on your iPhone.